# gdb on mojave works in terminal but not in vs code

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, gdb

After those tricks about codesigning, I've got to make gdb run on my mac (10.14.6), but only in terminal, and it gives no response in vs code.

Everything works just fine in terminal, like setting breakpoints, printing variables and running the executables, but it gets stuck in vs code, and nothing shows up in the variable and call stack sections.

Here's my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gdb",
            /* "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": false
                }
            ], */
            "preLaunchTask": "Build"
        }
    ]
}
```

[vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQGuQ.png)

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmcE2.png)

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using lldb instead? Which is the supported debugger on macos

Comment: Yeah, actually lldb works just fine. But I used to have a Windows machine, and was familiar with gdb, so I'm trying to see if I can get it work on a Mac, too.

Comment: I wouldn't bother, using the debugger command line is pretty painful in visual studio code at the moment and if you aren't using it then you shouldn't see any difference between gdb and lldb